# Как найти среднне значение из массива

Tags: javascript

Пример:

```
var avgsumm = [10, 20, 40, 1, 150, 78888, 50];
```

найти как то с данного массива среднее значение(число) не использовав function

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75759/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const avgsumm = [10, 20, 40, 1, 150, 78888, 50];
let sum = 0;

for (let index = 0; index < avgsumm.length; index++) {
    sum+=avgsumm[index];
}

let avg = sum/avgsumm.length;

console.log(avg);
```

Comment: Что означает reduce?

Comment: функциями нельзя пользоваться, судя из постановки

Comment: @КаренОганнисян https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @КаренОганнисян "reduce" означает "уменьшить"

Comment: @ThisMan да нельзя, но думаю что нужна другая версия какая то, что бы не reduce было, не / вот поэтому я тоже не пойму как сделать правильно

Comment: @КаренОганнисян исправил

Comment: А можно как то поменять строку let avg = sum/avgsumm.length; что бы / не было просто я не пойму для чего он, и такое точно не надо в данной задаче, с функцией я бы тоже написал)

Comment: @КаренОганнисян '/' - это знак деления...